# Azure Blob Storage mass delete items with specific names

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-cli

Let's say that I have a blob container that have the following files with names

```
2cfe4d2c-2703-4b0f-bed0-6b239f238206
1a18c31f-bf28-4f64-a796-79237fabc66a
20a300dd-c032-405f-b67d-9c077623c26c
6f4041dd-92da-484a-966d-d5a168a9a2ec
(Let's say there are around ~15000 files)
```

I want to delete around 1200 of them. I have a file with all the names I want to delete. In my case, I have it in JSON but it does not really matter in what kinda format it is; I know the files I wanna delete.

What is the most efficient/safe way to delete these items?

I can think of a few ways. For example, using `az storage blob deletebatch` or `az storage blob delete` . I am sure that the former is more efficient but I would not know how to do this because there is not really a pattern, just a big list of guids (names) that I want to delete.

I guess I would have to write some code to iterate over my list of files to delete and then use the CLI or some azure storage library to delete them.

I'd prefer to just use some built-in tooling but I can't find a way to do this without having to write code to talk with the API.

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tool `azcopy` would be perfect for that. Using the command [`azcopy remove`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-remove) you can specify a path to a text file using the parameter `--list-of-files={path}` to filter on specific files. The file should be plain text and line delimited.